# The proper term for responding -- "Boruch Dayan HaEmes" or just "Emes"?

Tags: blessing, death

When an an avel makes the brocha "Boruch Dayan HaEmes," the term is "**HaEmes**". However, I often hear people reply "Boruch Dayan **Emes**" when they hear news of a death. Is that a proper term or should their reply be "Boruch Dayan HaEmes" like the avel himself?

Comment: Can you clarify which (if any) of the listed cases include an implied "Attah Hashem Elokeinu Melech Haolam"?

Comment: I don't think "Emes" is correct; have no source though

Answer (score 4):

Answer: `Their reply be "Boruch Dayan HaEmes" like the avel himself.`

Background:

Says the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 59:6 (and you'll find similar wording in the [Rambam](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2510.htm) and the Shulchan Aruch):

> מֵת אָבִיו אוֹ אֶחָד מִשְּׁאָר קְרוֹבָיו, אוֹ אֲפִלּוּ אֵינוֹ קְרוֹבוֹ אֶלָּא שֶׁהוּא אָדָם כָּשֵׁר, וּמִכָּל שֶׁכֵּן תַּלְמִיד חָכָם שֶׁהוּא מִצְטַעֵר עָלָיו, מְבָרֵךְ בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' אֱ-לֹקֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, **דַּיַּן הָאֱמֶת**. וְעַל שְׁאָר אָדָם שֶׁאֵינוֹ מִצְטַעֵר כָּל כָּךְ, אוֹמֵר **בָּרוּךְ דַיַּן הָאֱמֶת** בְּלֹא שֵׁם וּמַלְכוּת

"If somebody one is very close to,  dies, one says the full Bracha of בָּרוּךְ דַיַּן הָאֱמֶת.  Upon hearing other sad news one says "בָּרוּךְ דַיַּן הָאֱמֶת"

There is an expression `דַּיַן אֱמֶת` and the Rambam ([Hil. Brachot 2:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2502.htm)) and Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 199) bring it - it's in the special Birkat HaMazon for the Avel:

> הַמֶּלֶךְ הַחַי הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב אֵ-ל אֱמֶת **דַּיַן אֱמֶת** שׁוֹפֵט בְּצֶדֶק שַׁלִּיט בְּעוֹלָמוֹ לַעֲשׂוֹת בּוֹ כִּרְצוֹנוֹ שֶׁאֲנַחְנוּ עַמּוֹ וַעֲבָדָיו וּבַכּל אֲנַחְנוּ חַיָּבִין לְהוֹדוֹת לוֹ וּלְבָרְכוֹ

Comment: This looks oddly like you copied/pasted this answer. If so, it is likely (and ought) to be deleted.  If you copied part of the answer, please make clear the source (eg., with a link) and set it apart from your own contribution. Intro/closing statement(s) would help. You usually contribute very good content, so I'm pointing out the issues so you can fix them.

Comment: @SethJ - I'll take that as a compliment that my writing has improved. But I wrote this up from scratch, though I  copy & pasted the "Hebrew" from their primary sources.

Comment: Well, I wasn't judging on skill; just the style looked like it might have been lifted from an ask-the-rabbi site or something. I hope I didn't offend you. @Mods, delete or retain the comments at your discretion.